# Why can't display some columns in public site of salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex

This is full code:
Controller:

```
public class TestController {
    public List<MyProduct__c> MyProducts {get;set;}
   
    public string searchstring {
        get{
            if (searchstring==null) searchstring = '';
            return searchstring;
           }
        set;} 
    public TestController()
    {
       search();
    }
    
   public void search(){ 
        string searchquery='select Product_Code__c,name,price__c,imagename__c from MyProduct__c where name like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' Limit 20'; 
        MyProducts= Database.query(searchquery);        
       
   } 
}
```

Home Page is a visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="TestController"  >
   <apex:form >       
     <div align="center">
           <apex:inputText style="width: 360px; height: 25px" value="{!searchstring}" label="Input"/> 
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" /> 
      </div>            
    
      <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result"> 
              
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!MyProducts}" var="a"> 
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:image width="100" height="100" value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProductImage, 'ProductImage/' & a.ImageName__c)}"></apex:image>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column value="{!a.ImageName__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!a.Product_Code__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!a.Price__c}"/>              
            </apex:pageblockTable>         

        </apex:pageBlock> 
   </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Result when click Preview from Developer Console:
It display 4 columns and image view ok.
[image]

But if Run from a public site and not login salesforce:
It only display 2 columns:
[image]

Why can't display 2 columns(ImageName__c,Price__c) in public site?

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with permissions.

Visualforce is a framework that enforces Salesforce's security measures directly, so if the user which is accessing the Visualforce page does not have permission to see a certain field, it will not render it.

I would suggest you check profiles/permission sets and verify that the user accessing the page has enough access.

Comment: MyProduct__c  is a custom Object, add 3 columns : Product_Code__c,ImageName__c, Price__c. but Product_Code__c is ok.

Comment: I think you haven't understood the answer: check the profiles and permission sets.

Comment: If permission not allow ,Product_Code__c can't display?